# Java JDBC connecting in docker can't connect to host database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, jdbc

I have a Maven container running Spring Boot and connecting to a database with JDBC.

I want connect to host database

(**host**: Ubuntu/18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver))

(**database**: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper)

This is my connection string

```
this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://172.24.0.1:3306/myDB?"+"user=xxxx&password=xxxx");
```

This is my container IP

```
$ip route show
default via 172.24.0.1 dev eth0
172.24.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.10
```

I can telnet and mysql login with IP 172.24.0.1 or 172.17.0.1 in Maven container

```
$telnet 172.24.0.1 3306
Trying 172.24.0.1...
Connected to 172.24.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

telnet 172.17.0.1 3306
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However, I can't connect via JDBC with IP 172.24.0.1 or 172.17.0.1.

Comment: Define "can't connect".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the database that is installed on the host machine where your docker image runs, then the host name in your connection string should be host.docker.internal.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/myDB?"+"user=xxxx&password=xxxx");
```

Comment: AFAIK, host.docker.internal only works on Windows hosts. On Linux you can use 172.17.0.1 to access the host.

Comment: @HansKilian i change my connection string to 172.17.0.1 but it still doesn't work